# how to Submitting iframes forms from the orginal page?

Tags: jquery, html

i have some iframes in one page each one of them containing form !! i want to put one button in the original page which submitting all this forms in the iframes together !!
so is that possible ??

```
<div id="LG"><iframe name="Stack" src="lg.php" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' ></iframe></div>
<div id="Toshiba"><iframe name="Stack" src="toshiba.php" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' ></iframe></div>
<div id="Sony"><iframe name="Stack" src="sony.php" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' ></iframe></div>
<div id="PANASONIC"><iframe name="Stack" src="panasonic.php" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' ></iframe></div>
<div id="BenQ"><iframe name="Stack" src="benq.php" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' ></iframe></div>
<div align="right"><button class="btn btn-success inserting" type="submit" name="save" value="save">Save Into DataBase</button></div>
```

so how can i call the forms from the iframes and make them all submitting with this button click ??

Comment: Why not just put all the divs on the same page, in the same form?

Comment: this divs are the body of tabs above so each page have alot of code it will be crappy page i won't able to read it if i did that also it can't be one form for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely possible with JS.

You should give each iframe an ID, then access them with:

```
$('#iFrameID').contents().find('#formData');
```

Or without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('iFrameID').contentDocument.getElementById('formData');
```

So all you need to do is, on submit fetch all the data and process it like you need to.

**Submitting individual forms in each iframes using jquery:**

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    $('iframe').each(function() {
         $(this).contents().find('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: @MahmoudAhmed Yes. Depends how you are grabbing the form data. Getting the form ID will contain all the children data (inputs and such).

Comment: no i don't want to grabbing the form data all i want is to make this button submit it the same like the form button

Comment: @MahmoudAhmed So you just want to submit each iframe separately? If so you can just trigger each submit button in each iframe (if they don't have a submit button, you can just use jQuery to submit the form) If thats what you want I will modify my answer to reflect that.

Comment: yes i want to submit each iframe separately !! but only on this button click? so is it possible ?

Comment: @MahmoudAhmed I edited the answer above for it to submit all forms and will work as long as you only have one form per iframe.